# How to pass authorization token to a Server Component in Next.js 13 with app directory?

Tags: authentication, cookies, next.js, http-headers, server-side-rendering

I am new to Next.js and am storing a JWT authorization token in the client-side React Context and would like to 'pass' that token from the client-side context to a server component so that it can be retrieved from the server component via the [`headers()`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/headers) or [`cookies()`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cookies) functions.

I am assuming I need to 'set' these headers and cookies on the client-only code, but how?

I'd prefer to use `headers()` as I can control when/whether the credentials are sent or not; with cookies, I am assuming it's always sent with every request.

There is an [Authentication](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication) documentation for the stable version of Next.js 13, but I have started with the app directory (beta) version which doesn't use `getServerSideProps()`.

The stable documentation also mentions `iron-session` and I found this [issue](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/issues/560#issuecomment-1324598048) with an example of how to read the cookie in Next.js 13, but it doesn't show how to set it.

***tl;dr* How do I set headers and cookies client-side so they can be read via the [`headers()`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/headers) or [`cookies()`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cookies) functions in a server component?**

Answer (score 3):

- When user signs in, you send the credentials to `pages/api/auth/login`. you check the verification and create a token.

I use `cookies-next` library to deal with the cookies.

```
import { setCookie } from "cookies-next";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest,res: NextApiResponse)
 {
  // pass all the checking
  const token = await jwt.sign(credentials,secret)
  setCookie("jwt", token, { req, res, maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 });
}
```

- everytime you make a request, you attach the token to the header.

Using `cookies-next`

```
  import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";

  const jwt = getCookie("jwt");

 const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.BASE/whatever}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
    },
  });
```

- Before in serverside functions, we could access to `req` object and check if the user is authenticated or not. To handle this in next.js I create an endpoint `api/auth/me`. I sent a request to this endpoint to check if the user has a valid jwt or not. I have to do this in top-level component of the app directory. I created an Authentication Context and inside `useEffect` I check the status of the user. I will keep track of the state:

in Authentication Context, client component

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
    setAuthState({
      data: null,
      error: null,
      loading: true,
    });
    try {
      const jwt = getCookie("jwt");

      if (!jwt) {
        return setAuthState({
          data: null,
          error: null,
          loading: false,
        });
      }

      const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.BASE/api/auth/me}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
        },
      });

      setAuthState({
        data: response.data,
        error: null,
        loading: false,
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      setAuthState({
        data: null,
        error: error.response.data.errorMessage,
        loading: false,
      });
    }
  };

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchUser();
   }, []);
```

- this is `pages/api/auth/me` endpoint.

I make a request here inside auth context

```
 export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest,res: NextApiResponse)
 {
  const bearerToken = req.headers["authorization"] as string;
  const token = bearerToken.split(" ")[1];

  const payload = jwt.decode(token) as { email: string };

  if (!payload.email) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      errorMessage: "Unauthorized request",
    });
  }

  const user = yourFetchUser(payload.email)

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      errorMessage: "User not found",
    });
  }

  return res.json({...user});
}
```

- check if the user is authenticated inside navbar.

this is a client component

```
const { data, loading } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);
```

Based on data you set conditionally display user name or sign in button.

- finally using `cookies-next` sign out is very easy

  ```
  import { removeCookies } from "cookies-next";

  removeCookies("jwt");
  ```

Comment: it is not safe to store access token in cookie as it gets exposted.

Comment: @DK - it's encrypted and the jwt token is always stored in a cookies. It's as secure as it can be, but you can (and should) set an expiration on it though.

Answer (score 1):

What @dayuloli said does work. I had used it.

middleware.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

    const headers = new Headers(request.headers);
    headers.set('middlewareSet', 'mydata');

    const resp = NextResponse.next({
      request: {
        headers
      }
    });    

    return resp;
}
```

server page:

```
export default async function PageServer() {
  
  const headersList = headers()
  const middlewareSet = headersList.get('middlewareSet') || ''
  
}
```

Comment: Does it work? Middleware runs in server, I don't think it can access client credential.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but I recently noticed this new section in the documentation about [middlewares](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#setting-headers) that makes it seem like it's possible to pass information to the server via request headers *and not via cookies*:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // Clone the request headers and set a new header `x-hello-from-middleware1`
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set('x-hello-from-middleware1', 'hello');
 
  // You can also set request headers in NextResponse.rewrite
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      // New request headers
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
 
  // Set a new response header `x-hello-from-middleware2`
  response.headers.set('x-hello-from-middleware2', 'hello');
  return response;
}
```